# decision with overflow-y and motion of submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-web-developer

the description is next:
I made fixed menu with fixed height, the menu include second submenu.
When cursor hover over li, the second submenu of li moves across area of parent. 
The Menu of 1lvl has a lof of included li. I use overflow-y:scroll for lookup of all items of menu 1lvl.
The problem which i need the help: 
"Overflow-y" activates "overflow-x"(...ow-x:auto) and it breaks motion of submenu.
What i can make for scroll elements into menu and normal work of motion of submenu?
HTML:

```
    <div class="ear_panel">
        <ul class="lvl_1">
            <li class="cl1">
                <span>m1</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>1.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>1.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl2">
            <span>m2</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li>
                        <span>2.1</span>
                        <ul class="lvl_3">
                            <li><span>2.1.1</span></li>
                            <li><span>2.1.2</span></li>
                            <li><span>2.1.3</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl3">
                <span>m3</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>3.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>3.2</span></li>
                    <li><span>3.3</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl4">
                <span>m4</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>4.1</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl5">
                <span>m5</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>5.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl6">
                <span>m6</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>документы</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl7">
                <span>m7</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>документооборот</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl8">
                <span>m8</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl9">
                <span>m9</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl10">
                <span>m10</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl11">
                <span>m11</span>
                <ul class="lvl_2">
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                    <li><span>other</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cl12"><span>1</span></li>
            <li class="cl13"><span>2</span></li>
            <li class="cl14"><span>3</span></li>
            <li class="cl15"><span>4</span></li>
            <li class="cl16"><span>5</span></li>
            <li class="cl17"><span>6</span></li>
            <li class="cl18"><span>7</span></li>
            <li class="cl19"><span>8</span></li>
            <li class="cl20"><span>9</span></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

css:

```
.ear_panel
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 130px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        //overflow-y: scroll; uncomment for break menu
    }

    .ear_panel *
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        transition: .4s;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    .ear_panel span
    {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .ear_panel ul
    {
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1
    {
        text-align: center;

    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1 li
    {
        height: 55px;
        background-color: #1E4387;
        margin: 0;
        text-align:center;
        cursor: default;
        position: relative;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        color: #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(129,132,134);
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1 li:last-child
    {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(129,132,134);
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1>li>span
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
    }
    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1>li:hover>span
    {
        top: 20px;
    }



    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1 li:hover
    {
        background-color: rgb(0,138,210);   
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: -333px;
        top: -1px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility:hidden;
        transition: .4s;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 li
    {
        height: 38px;
        width: 185px;
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        left: 30px;
        border: none;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2>li>span
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 8px;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1 li:hover ul.lvl_2,
    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 li:hover ul.lvl_3
    {
        opacity:  1;
        visibility:visible;
        left: 116px;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 li:hover ul.lvl_3
    {
        left: 124px;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_3
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -1px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility:hidden;
        transition: .4s;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 ul.lvl_3
    {
        margin-left: 33px;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 .lvl_3 span
    {
        top: 8px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2 .lvl_3 span,
    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2  span
    {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    /*код расположения иконок в блоках уровня 1*/
    /*Их общшие свойства*/
    .ear_panel ul.lvl_1>li:before
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: .2;
        font-size: 44px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s;
        -moz-transition: all .6s;
        transition: all .6s;
        font-family: "icomoon_test";
        font-size: 50px;
        top: 0;
    }

    .ear_panel ul.lvl_2>li:hover>span
    {
        left: 20px;
    }
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hk2jvL1c/7/)